# Use different Entity Manager in the Repository of specific Entity objects

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I've followed the [How to Work with multiple Entity Managers and Connections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) chapter in the manual to configure and use different entity managers in my app, as some entities are stored in different database servers.

In the controller I need to use the 2 entity managers: the default for clients, numbers and payments, and the other for contracts.

However, when I call the repository custom method `fetchMainByClient()` for contracts, which should use the "custom" entity manager instead of the default one, I get a database error, which shows that's using the default entity manager in the repository.

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT ...  FROM CONTRACTS c0_
>   WHERE c0_.ClientId = ? AND c0_.Type = 'Main'' with params [35736]:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'DEFAULTDB.CONTRACTS' doesn't exist

The same error occurs if I try to use an already available repository method, like `findOneBy()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the Controller's, the Repository's code and the Contract entity header, as well as the doctrine configuration. It's not the real one, but it's similar.

### Controller

```
public function index(Request $request, PaymentsRepository $payments_repository): Response
{
    $payments = $payments_repository->findLatest($page, $this->getUser()->getId());

    $form = $this->createForm(CreatePaymentType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $payment = $form->getData();

        $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
        $cr = $em->getRepository(Numbers::class);
        $number = $tr->findOneByNumber($payment->getNumber());

        if (!$number) {
            $this->addFlash('error', 'numbers.missing_number');
        } else {
            $client = $number->getClients();
            if (!$client) {
                $this->addFlash('error', 'clients.missing_client');
            } else {
                //$em_custom = $this->get('doctrine.orm.custom_entity_manager');
                $em_custom = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('custom');
                $contracts_repo = $em_custom->getRepository(Contracts::class);
                //dump($em, $em_custom, $contracts_repo);

                $contract = $contracts_repo->fetchMainByClient($client->getId());
                $contracts_repo->increaseCredit($payment->getValue());

                $payment->setDate(...);
                $payment->setClientId($client->getId());
                ...
                $em->persist($payment);
                $em->flush();

                $this->addFlash('success', 'flash.success_insert');

                return $this->redirectToRoute('payments_paginated', ['page' => $page]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('carregamentos/index.html.twig', [
        'payments' => $payments,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

### Repository

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Custom\Contratos;

...
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class ContractsRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Contracts::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return Contracts Returns the Contracts object for the ClientId
     */
    public function fetchMainByClient($value): ?Contracts
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->andWhere('c.clientid = :val')
            ->andWhere('c.type = \'Main\'')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }
}
```

### Doctrine configuration

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.6'
                charset: utf8
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8
                    collate: utf8_unicode_ci

                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

            custom:
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.6'
                charset: utf8
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8
                    collate: utf8_unicode_ci

                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_CUSTOM_URL)%'
                mapping_types:
                    enum: string
                    set:  string

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: Main
            custom:
                connection: custom
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                mappings:
                    Custom:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Custom'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Custom'
                        alias: Custom
```

### Entity header with ORM mapping

```
namespace App\Entity\Custom;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Contracts.
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="CONTRACTS", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="clientid", columns={"clientid"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ContractsRepository")
 */
class Contracts
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, you say the contract class is in the custom entity manager, but it has the namespace of the default one?

Comment: The default namespace is App\Entity, and the Contract class is in the App\Entity\Ims namespace. Why do you say so, @LioraHaydont?

Comment: I might be wrong, I have never worked with multiple entities manager, but in your custom em you set `prefix: 'App\Entity\Custom'`, so my guess would have been that the entity namespace would be `App\Entity\Custom\Ims`

Comment: That's an error when passing the original code to this example. It's updated and fixed.
For The namespace is `App\Entity\Custom`, as well as the namespace.

Ims refers to the original one.

Comment: I guess you checked manually the database and the tables are in the right databases?

Comment: Yes, used doctrine:schema:import and validate from both the databases and worked well.

Comment: The problem is that your default connection will pick up all entities in App\Entity as well as any sub-directories such as App\Entity\Custom.  So your custom entities are being mapped to both entity managers.  The service repository constructor just looks through each manager to see if it supports a given entity.  First one found get's the repository.  Move App\Entity\Custom to something like App\EntityCustom.

Comment: Thank you @Cerad, it worked!
Please add your comment as an answer so that I mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your default connection will pick up all entities in App\Entity as well as any sub-directories such as App\Entity\Custom. So your custom entities are being mapped to both entity managers.

The service repository constructor just looks through each manager to see if it supports a given entity. First one found get's the repository.

Move App\Entity\Custom to something like App\EntityCustom and adjust the config.