# Problems while using multiple databases

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Background: I am developing a web application with Symfony5 for a customer. The application should be available for several customers. Each customer should get his own file directory (for pdf etc.) and database. The file-directory is not the problem, but I can't get anywhere with the databases.
According to the [Symfony docu](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) you can work with different DBs. I configured this in the config/packages/doctrine.yaml.

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    connections:
        Client1:
            dbname:     client1
            host:       localhost
            port:       3306
            user:       admin
            password:   secret_pw
            driver:     pdo_mysql
            server-version: 5.7
        Client2:
            dbname:     client2
            host:       localhost
            port:       3306
            user:       admin
            password:   secret_pw
            driver:     pdo_mysql
            server-version: 5.7
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    entity_managers:
        Client1:
            connection: Client1
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
            mappings:
                Client1:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: Client1
        Client2:
            connection: Client2
            naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
            mappings:
                Client2:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                    prefix: 'App\Entity'
                    alias: Client2
```

So far it also works, if I create the database from the CLI and execute the migrations.

But if I want to read e.g. a user from the DB for Client2 (is set in $dbClient) with

```
$userRepo = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(User::class, $dbClient);
$user = $userRepo->findOneByeEmail($this->userEmail);
```

the DB for Client1 is ALWAYS set in the repo :((.

Did I do something wrong in the config?
Or is there something else that needs to be configured elsewhere?

Thank you very much for your help

Frank

Comment: checkout this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59550479/10464991), I think that might help you

Answer (score 0):

Both entity managers have the same prefix in your mappings. You should try something like

```
prefix: 'App\Entity\Client1'
//...
prefix: 'App\Entity\Client2'
```

That's what they do in the doc.

Comment: Thanks Bob, but that would mean that I would have to mirror the directory structure for each client. Isn't there some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You inject wrong entity manager

`$this->getDoctrine()->getManager('Client2')>getRepository(User::class)->findOneByeEmail($this->userEmail);`